# Split-Path with : in the path

Tags: powershell

I have an odd Registry path that Autodesk AutoCAD uses, and I need to do a Split-Path on it to then push a value to Default. The path is

***HKCU\Software\Autodesk\DWGCommon\shellex\Apps{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}:AutoCAD(Default)***

That **:** before AutoCAD is making trouble in PoSH 2.0, where Split-Path -parent returns everything before the :, rather than including :AutoCAD as it should. I tried -literalPath and it seems that's newer than 2.0, correct? Anyone have any thoughts?

EDIT: To clarify, a correct result would be a parent of
***HKCU\Software\Autodesk\DWGCommon\shellex\Apps{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}:AutoCAD***
and a leaf of 
***(Default)***
The info above is somewhat erroneous in that I am typing a BACKSLASH between AutoCAD & (Default) but it is getting dropped by the editor. :( And I just noticed the same is true of a \ after Apps and before the opening curly brace. I just tried escaping the curly braces, on a lark, but that didn't help. It still treats the : as a drive delimiter and barfs looking for a drive called 
HKCU\Software\Autodesk\DWGCommon\shellex\Apps{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}, but with the backslash after Apps that still won't show up. Dang, maybe I just need to give up and go have a beer. It is 9:30 on a Friday night after all.

Comment: Do you just want to split the string at the colon? Does http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/07/17/using-the-split-method-in-powershell.aspx help?

Comment: I edited the OP to clarify. The problem is that colon is real, and is in the middle of the parent Key name. I suspect using a colon like that is not as Microsoft intended, but Autodesk is kinda famous for not getting basic OS stuff right. Until VERY recently they still put user config files in Program Files and suggested that we make all our users Local Admins. Let me think about it NO! ;)

Comment: Try `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName('HKCU\Software\Autodesk\DWGCommon\shellex\Apps{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}:AutoCAD\(Default)')`. I'm not sure if this works, because I can't test it on PS 2.0.

Comment: Hmm, seems it might not matter, because even if I got the variables from Split-Path I want, I can't use Set-ItemProperty because it too doesn't cope with a : in the path other than after the HKCU. I think Autodesk just totally failed to read the white paper and name this stuff right.

Comment: beatcracker, that works, in that it returns (default) correctly. But unless there is an alternative to writing to the registry with Set-ItemProperty I may still be sunk. But there seems to be a ton of .NET alternatives to "native" PoSH, so I'll hold out some hope. ;)

Comment: For what it's worth, my UAK (Ugly @ss Kludge) is to automate merging a REG file. It works, but if something does fail it doesn't return an error, so I can't log one, which is far from ideal. But at least my customer has an alternative solution to an edge case problem, so that's good.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `Split-Path` to recognize the path as *rooted*, you'll have to introduce an artifical ":" after the first component:

```
$Path = "HKCU\Software\Autodesk\DWGCommon\shellex\Apps{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}:AutoCAD(Default)"

# Find first occurrence of \
$FirstSplit = $Path.IndexOf('\')

if($Path[$FirstSplit - 1] -ne ':'){
    $RootedPath = $Path.Insert($FirstSplit, ':')
}

$Value = Split-Path $RootedPath -Leaf
# Remove ":" again
$Key = (Split-Path $RootedPath -Parent).Remove($FirstSplit,1)
```

Now, they should have been split properly:

```
PS C:\> "{0}`n  {1}" -f $key,$value
HKCU\Software\Autodesk\DWGCommon\shellex
  Apps{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}:AutoCAD(Default)
```